# Why is some part of a DVD (video) unskippable and how can it be bypassed?

Tags: dvd

I have found 3 states of a DVD player:

- Able to jump to disc menu, able to skip chapter
- Unable to jump to disc menu, but still able to skip chapter
- Unable to both jump to disc menu and skip chapter

Why does my DVD-player/program enforce this? How can it be bypassed?

Comment: I think the goal is that this isn't bypassed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DVD licensing authority tries to require that players enforce this, based on flags encoded into the DVD. The way round it is to get an unlicensed player that doesn't; VLC on a computer, or if you want a physical DVD player to connect to your TV then generally the cheap unbranded ones are less likely to enforce the restrictions (including region locking).